# Haproxy SSL(https) health checks without terminating ssl

Tags: haproxy

so I can't figure out a proper way to do the SSL check, I am not using certificates, just need to check against a HTTPS websites url (google.com/ for example)
Trying multiple combinations at a time, without success. Maybe someone has a similar configuration,

backends using -
>     check-sni google.com sni ssl_fc_sni

> ```
>     returns - reason: Layer7 wrong status, code: 301, info: "Moved Permanently"
> ```

check port 80 check-ssl -

> reason: Layer6 invalid response, info: "SSL handshake failure"

**All others just timing out. Here's the complete configuration file-**

```
global
        log /dev/log    local0
        log /dev/log    local1 notice
        chroot /var/lib/haproxy
        stats socket /run/haproxy/admin.sock mode 660 level admin
        stats timeout 30s
        user haproxy
        group haproxy
        daemon

        # Default SSL material locations
        ca-base /etc/ssl/certs
        crt-base /etc/ssl/private
        ssl-server-verify none
        # Default ciphers to use on SSL-enabled listening sockets.
        # For more information, see ciphers(1SSL). This list is from:
        #  https://hynek.me/articles/hardening-your-web-servers-ssl-ciphers/
        # An alternative list with additional directives can be obtained from
        #  https://mozilla.github.io/server-side-tls/ssl-config-generator/?server=haproxy
        ssl-default-bind-ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:RSA+AESGCM:RSA+AES:!aNULL:!MD5:!DSS
        ssl-default-bind-options no-sslv3

defaults
        log     global
        mode    http
        option  httplog
        option  dontlognull
        timeout connect 5000
        timeout client  50000
        timeout server  50000
        errorfile 400 /etc/haproxy/errors/400.http
        errorfile 403 /etc/haproxy/errors/403.http
        errorfile 408 /etc/haproxy/errors/408.http
        errorfile 500 /etc/haproxy/errors/500.http
        errorfile 502 /etc/haproxy/errors/502.http
        errorfile 503 /etc/haproxy/errors/503.http
        errorfile 504 /etc/haproxy/errors/504.http



frontend myfront
bind *:8000
mode tcp
        tcp-request inspect-delay 5s

default_backend backend1



listen stats
bind :444
stats enable
stats uri /
stats hide-version
stats auth test:test

backend Backends
balance roundrobin
option forwardfor

option httpchk

  http-check send hdr host google.com meth GET uri /

 http-check expect status 200
#http-check connect
#http-check send meth GET uri / ver HTTP/1.1 hdr host haproxy.1wt.eu
#http-check expect status 200-399
#http-check connect port 443 ssl sni haproxy.1wt.eu
#http-check send meth GET uri / ver HTTP/1.1 hdr host haproxy.1wt.eu
#http-check expect status 200-399
#http-check connect port 443 ssl sni google.com
#http-check send meth GET uri / ver HTTP/1.1 hdr host google.com


   default-server fall 10 rise 1




 server Node1011 192.168.0.2:1011 check inter 15s check-ssl check port 443
 server Node1012 192.168.0.2:1012 check inter 15s check-ssl check port 443
 server Node1015 192.168.0.2:1015 check inter 15s check port 443
 server Node1017 192.168.0.2:1017 check inter 15s check-ssl check-sni google.com sni ssl_fc_sni
 server Node1018 192.168.0.2:1018 check inter 15s check-ssl check-sni google.com sni ssl_fc_sni
 server Node1019 192.168.0.2:1019 check inter 15s check-sni google.com sni ssl_fc_sni
 server Node1020 192.168.0.2:1020 check inter 15s check port 443 check-ssl
 server Node1021 192.168.0.2:1021 check inter 15s check port 443 check-ssl

 server Node1027 192.168.0.2:1027 check inter 15s check port 80
 server Node1028 192.168.0.2:1028 check inter 15s check port 80
 server Node1029 192.168.0.2:1029 check inter 15s check port 80
 server Node1030 192.168.0.2:1030 check inter 15s check port 80 check-ssl
 server Node1031 192.168.0.2:1031 check inter 15s check port 80 check-ssl

 server Node1033 192.168.0.2:1033 check inter 15s check port 80 check-ssl verify none
 server Node1034 192.168.0.2:1034 check inter 15s check port 80 check-ssl verify none
 server Node1035 192.168.0.2:1035 check inter 15s check-ssl
 server Node1036 192.168.0.2:1036 check inter 15s check-ssl

 server Node1048 192.168.0.2:1048 check inter 15s check-ssl verify none
 server Node1049 192.168.0.2:1049 check inter 15s check-ssl verify none
```

P.s Found a website, which explains just what I'm trying to do(https://hodari.be/posts/2020_09_04_configure_sni_for_haproxy_backends/), but that doesn't work either, my **haproxy version is 2.2.3**

P.s.s I am literally trying to check against [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) , just to be clear.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

That's really not an error.  If you do a curl to `https://google.com` it does do a 301 redirect to `https://www.google.com/`.  I snipped out some protocol details below for brevity, but you get the idea.

Either change your expect to 301, or use `www.google.com`.

```
paul:~ $ curl -vv https://google.com
* Rebuilt URL to: https://google.com/
*   Trying 172.217.1.206...
-[snip]-
> GET / HTTP/2
> Host: google.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
> Accept: */*
> 
-[snip]-
< HTTP/2 301 
< location: https://www.google.com/
< content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
< date: Mon, 18 Jan 2021 03:42:04 GMT
< expires: Wed, 17 Feb 2021 03:42:04 GMT
< cache-control: public, max-age=2592000
< server: gws
< content-length: 220
< x-xss-protection: 0
< x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
< alt-svc: h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-T051=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000,quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43"
< 
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS Unknown, Unknown (23):
<HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<TITLE>301 Moved</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>
<H1>301 Moved</H1>
The document has moved
<A HREF="https://www.google.com/">here</A>.
</BODY></HTML>
```

So, if you want to avoid the 301, use the `www.google.com` value in your config as thus:

```
http-check send hdr host www.google.com meth GET uri /
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but unfortunately I need to get a real response from HTTPS website, that's the only reason why I am trying to force SSL

Comment: 301 **is** a real response.  If you want a 200, just use `https://www.google.com/`

Comment: Sorry, I have misinterpreted that, I need a value from response body, will try the https:// option, although I have never seen it used in a configuration. Will report back shortly! Thanks!

Comment: Actually, I was suggesting to use `www.google.com` instead of  `google.com` to avoid the 301.

Comment: Still no luck, website is configured only for HTTPS, so even using www.google.com results in a 301 :( 
P.s I am literally testing again www.google.com